# How to use a function defined in another file with g++?

Tags: c++, linker, g++

This is a really basic question, and I have found a lot of conceptual answers online, but failed to actually make it work.

Here is what I have:

file source.cc

```
#include <iostream>

int myfunc() {
  return 42;
}

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

and then I create an object file source.o via:

```
g++ -c source.cc
```

finally, I use

```
ar rvs source.a source.o
```

to get the source.a static library.

Now, here comes trouble.

file user.cc looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <source.a>

int main() {
  std::cout << myfunc();
}
```

where I evidently want to use the function defined in the library, but when trying to compile the user.cc:

```
g++ user.cc -o user
```

the error I get is:

```
user.cc:2:22: fatal error: source.a: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Angle brackets typically don't search the current directory, but that's beside the point. I highly doubt you want to include a .a file. Link to it.

Comment: You don't *include* a library, you *link* a library. You also need a declaration of the function (usually placed in a header file). You might also see issues with linking a library that also defines a `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what others already wrote on the syntax to properly use g++ on the command line, you may want to consider the following notes on your **code organization**.

In your **library code**, you should *not* define the `main()` function. The definition of `main()` should instead be part of the code that *uses* your library, i.e the file `user.cc` in your example.

Moreover, you may want to distribute to the clients of the library a **header file**, that they can use to import the *declarations* of the functions exported by the library.

So, consider defining some files like this:

**Header File:**

```
// library.h -- Public header for your library's clients

#pragma once   // or use #ifndef/#define/#endif "header guards"

// Functions exported by your library: 
// their *declarations* go in the library's public header file;
// their *definitions* go in the library's implementation file(s) (.cc, .cpp)
// (exception: inline functions/methods, that are implemented in headers).

int myfunc();

// Add some other exported functions...

// NOTE: "extern" not needed in C++!
```

**Implementation File:**

```
// library.cc -- Library implementation code
#include "library.h" // library public header 
#include <...>       // headers required by this implementation code

// *Define* functions exported by the library

int myfunc() {
    return 42;
}

// ...other function implementations...
```

Then, the library's client will just do:

**File containing `main()` and using your library:**

```
// main.cc (or user.cc or whatever you call it)

#include <iostream>   // For std::cout, std::endl
...#include any other required header file...

#include "library.h"  // Your library public header file

int main() {
    // Call library's function
    std::cout << myfunc() << std::endl;
}    

// NOTE: main() is special: "return 0;" can be omitted.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this cleared up a lot to me! Now that I have the header source.h and source.cc, I have compiled the main.cc to main.o, do I still need to link the library?

Comment: @mihapriimek: I'm glad it helped. BTW: As a good Stackoverflow citizen, you may want to upvote all the answers that you found helpful (and there are several in this thread), and mark the best as answer.

Comment: Sure, I was just trying to figure out which one helped me the most by trying all the different things people suggested. (before upvoting a particular answer)

Comment: Can I ask you about the significance of including the library header in the library? It worked without it.
Also, do the "" mean search in the current dir too?

Comment: Probably yours is a very simple case, but in general you can have structures and classes defined in the library header, and they can be referenced and used in library implementation code, hence the need to include the library header in the library.cc file.

Answer (score 3):

`#include` is compile time and must be C/C++ header (not library) containing e.g this

```
extern int myfunc();
```

than you have to use linker to compile it all togehter (specify all the files needed on the command line)

Comment: remove `extern`, it's redundant

Comment: But I consider it good practice, because you need it for variables. It is not bad to have it there and you don't have to think about where you need it and where not.

Comment: @firda: Honestly, exporting a global variable with `extern` seems to me a not very good practice... If you really need to share some form of global state, you may want to export some getter/setter **functions**. I agree in C++ `extern` for exported functions is redundant, and should be removed: I dislike it, just like I dislike `foo(void)` and instead prefer the simpler clearer `foo()` in C++.

Comment: I do use `foo()` and rewrite any `foo(void)` in old code, but cannot agree with the getter, why? Why would that be bad practice? What about global `shared_mutex`? That is perfect example, would you rather prefer few getters returning `lock_guard`, `unique_lock`, `shared_lock` and whatever?

Answer (score 2):

Don't `#include` a library archive. It does not contain source code. It contains object code. Put it on the linker's command line.

Compile with `g++ -c user.cc`.
Link with `g++ -o user user.o source.a`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ (and C99), every function you call much be declared ahead of time. To do this you provide the "signature" of the function, without the the definition. In your case, this would be the statement

```
int myfunc();
```

which tells the compiler that `myfunc` is a function which takes no arguments and returns an `int`. Typically you would include this function declaration in a header.

A `.a` file is a compiled archive which does not contain C or C++ code, so `#include`-ing it into a C++ file will not work. Instead you need to create a C or C++ header, and add the `.a` archive to the list of files to be linked into the final executable. With g++, this is quite easy, you can say

```
g++ user.cc source.a -o executable
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `#include <...>` construct (with angle brackets) search system directories to find the specified files. To search other directories you can use the `-L` option, and to link with your library you need to use `source.a` in the command line. Like this:

```
g++ user.cc -L/path/to/library source.a -o user
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas to add to the discussion
1) You should create a header file called source.h that contains the line

int myfunc(); 
or, 
extern int myfunc();

2) In user.cc at the top should be a line
  include "source.h"
This will tell the compiler the function is defined

3) I think you should take the main function out of source.cc, or at least make it static

As others have pointed out, you can't include a library file (source.a)
your compile and link process should work as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use headear files using `#include`. If you want to use libraries you have to tell the linker where to look for library files.

Check these articles for static and dynamic libraries:

[Static and dynamic libraries](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a1-static-and-dynamic-libraries/)

[Using libraries in VS2005](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a2-using-libraries-with-visual-studio-2005-express/)

[Using libraries in Code::Blocks](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/)